# The "flag posts" privilege page in the Help Center has outdated info on "rude or abusive" and "spam" flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, privileges-page, aged-away

[The help center page on flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) says:

> flags that aren't processed in a reasonable amount of time age away: rude or abusive and spam flags expire after 48 hours

But according to answers to this feature request ([Don't age away spam/rude/abusive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301828/997587)), [it was changed to 4 days in 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301833/997587), and [ageing-away was removed in 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379743/997587).

According to @Sonic in the comments (deleted as they're now quoted here):

> the portion about those flags being removed if the post is rolled back is also now incorrect.
>
> I found two other inaccuracies in the page:
>
> 1. the screenshot of the flag icon is outdated
> 2. posts are no longer banished from the front page with three spam/abusive flags (the only thing that kicks in is the usual removal if it's a question and scores -4 or below on a main site due to the implicit downvotes).

Can we update the help center page please?

Comment: @Sonic yeah, the whole page need someone to take a look and make it up to date.

Comment: *"R/A"* = *"rude or abusive"* (it isn't in [the glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)). [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor).

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: Are there other notable issues with this Help Center page besides the ones already listed in the post? If the community can identify (e.g. in an answer to this question) any other issues with this page that need to be fixed/updated, it'd make it easier for us to handle them all at once.

Comment: @V2Blast I'll take a look and ask around, thanks for the quick response. Is this trivial enough (time wise) to skip the review queue? :)

Comment: Well, if it's a simple change that'll take 5-10 minutes, I might just add the [status-review] tag and handle it myself. If the page needs to be more substantially rewritten, then I'd probably just follow the usual process.

Comment: @V2Blast looks like a simple change, please see my answer for the required changes, it also got reviewed by Sonic so should be ready to go. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I think it's fair that they go into the system details and check if there are other changes necessary. I may have missed something or made a mistake, after all.

Comment: @V2Blast Note that I changed the title of the question to reflect the fact that there are other changes which need to be done. I know from past experience that the title of the ticket in the internal support system matters a lot, so it would be nice if you updated the ticket to reflect the new title.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @Sonic perhaps, but it means waiting for very long time, most likely years, instead of few minutes fix. Personally I'd prefer a quick fix, which might not be 1000% perfect, but still better than the current state which is awful.

Comment: @V2Blast bump, reminding you about this one. I can't tell by now if it's 5-10 minutes change or not, what you think?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: It should hopefully still be pretty straightforward for whichever CM picks it up – though my previous time estimate didn't account for the need to get these changes translated for our international sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "flag posts" privilege page has been updated network-wide (including on international SOs) to have those sections removed.

Thank you for flagging!

Comment: All of the Help Center articles? What about the super secret mod Help Center articles?

Comment: Thank you kindly! "_Thank you for flagging!_" hehe you know me.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the OP's and Sonic observations, here is the summary of what needs to be changed:

1. The following paragraph:

   > Finally, flags that aren't processed in a reasonable amount of time age away: rude or abusive and spam flags expire after 48 hours (and are removed immediately if the post is rolled back to a revision prior to the one which was flagged); close flags expire after between 4-14 days (depending on other votes and views).

   Since the spam/abusive flags don't expire at all anymore and are also not removed anymore on rollbacks, the above paragraph should be shortened only to the close flags part:

   > Finally, close flags that aren't processed in a reasonable amount of time age away. They would expire after between 4-14 days (depending on other votes and views).
2. The following line under "What happens when I flag something as spam or rude/abusive?":

   > - 3 flags – the post is banished from the front page.

   Should be removed, that's not correct anymore.
3. The flag icon for comments was changed over time, from [image: old flag icon] to this: [image: new flag icon] (or [image: new flag icon when hovered] which appears when hovering the gray one, I'm not sure which to use in the help center page.)