# Prevent duplicate flag to be marked as "aged away"

Tags: discussion, flags, aged-away

I understand the use of the `aged away` flags for closing requests for old questions (since standards may have been changed etc.).

In https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/334095 I found that `aged away` is also used for ""Harassment, bigotry, or abuse" and "rude & abuse" flags after 4 day (not sure why, but I am okay with it).

However, I do not see why `duplicate` flags should be marked as `aged away`.

For example, I think [Making navigation links highlight when relevant element passes underneath it, using JavaScript/JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496235/making-navigation-links-highlight-when-relevant-element-passes-underneath-it-us) which is a less readable duplicate of [Change Active Menu Item on Page Scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979827/change-active-menu-item-on-page-scroll)

Both questions are only 5 months apart. Marking posts as duplicate is not rewarded in any way, so it only happens by chance.

I think in this case its a clear duplicate, and a duplicate note on the first question would be very helpful. My duplicate flag was marked as `aged away` unfortunatly.

Comment: When the flag age away, the comment is not deleted. Others can see this and cast new flag.

Comment: Although you've used the word flagged I guess with enough rep to close vote on SO you actually voted to close as a duplicate? It might be worth clarifying because while I've had a lot of flags age away I know close votes do expire but can't remember after how long and how it's displayed.

Comment: @PeterJ I am pretty sure I flagged it by pressing on "flag" and then on "a duplicate...". I found the flag in my profile under activity tab "x helpful flags" - although the duplicate flag was not appreciated as helpful.

Comment: @ShaWiz marking a question from 2011 as a duplicate happens once in a lifetime I guess :)

Comment: I wonder why the Meta effect hasn't yet kicked in...

Comment: @Luuklag meta effect is over-rated... :)

Comment: @PeterJ I just flagged another question as duplicate by clicking in the flag => "a duplicate" then selecting the duplicate, and then I have to click "vote to close". Its seems its not possible on SO to flag for duplicate without closing. The `aged away` was probably on the closing vote.